# Object property value changes before code exectuion

Tags: javascript, object, properties, expression, console.log

Hy guys thanks for checking out my question. I am investigating/researching something since 2 days, and I can not find out, why does it work, as it works.

So here is the code:

```js
var obj = {
 prop1 : "12",
 prop2 : {
  prop3 : 24,
  prop4 : "mother"
  } 
 }

newObj = obj;
console.log(newObj);
console.log(obj); 
 
newObj.prop2 = 1;
```

So I define here an object literal which in the creation phase of the build up of execution context, will get to be a key of the variable object of the current executionContextObject and than will be set to undefined.

And I change the obj.prop2-s value at the end of the code, but altough I change it at the end of the code my console.log() expressions, before the expression of:"newObj.prop2 = 1;" will show the muted properties.

What I dont uderstand here is, why this change - "newObj.prop2 = 1;" at the end of the code -, takes place before the interpreter arrives that line:"newObj.prop2 = 1;" and the console.log expressions are showing a change, which should happen just after them.

Thanks for reading my question until know.
If you just say what topic should I investigate to get an understanding about this phenomenon, would be enormously helpful.

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Thanks a lot now I see the answer